# PHP - Unit testing method with unmockable class in its body (PHPUnit)

Tags: php, unit-testing, eloquent, phpunit

I have a method that uses another class to calculate its outcome, that I want to test using PHPUnit.

```
/**
 * Returns true if the given user has been granted the given permission.
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @param AbstractPermission $permission
 * @return bool
 */
public function userPermissionGranted(User $user, AbstractPermission $permission) : bool
{
    // Retrieve model from database.
    $user_permission = UserPermission::scopeUser($user)
        ->scopePermission($permission)
        ->first();

    return $user_permission ? $user_permission->isGranted() : $permission->isGrantedByDefault();
}
```

Leaving out of consideration what this method actually does, I am wondering how to test this method. I can pass mocks of the `User` and `AbstractPermission` classes to the method, but the `UserPermission` class that is used inside the method's body (to retrieve a model from the database) I can do nothing with.

On top of that, if I pass mocks of the `User` and `Permisson` classes, they won't exist in the database, so when `UserPermission` queries the database, it will receive no results and the method will fail.

What do I do here? Is it considered good practice to simply mock the database (i.e. copying the live db structure and filling it with test data) and let my model query that database, and just trusting that everything is OK? Any suggestions on what to do here?

On a side note, `UserPermission` is an Eloquent model. I am merely making use of Eloquent here - without Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you can't directly mock static methods - at least, there's no good way to do it.  Depending on how your application is set up, you might be able to hack something together that involves redefining the method with runkit or perhaps messing with includes/autoloader to load a mock class instead of the real one, but such solutions are kludgey at best.

One simple approach to allow unit-testing would be to wrap your static method calls in an instance method.  So you'd create a new class with instance methods that call the static methods.  Of course, you wouldn't be able to test that *new* class, but if it's a thin wrapper around the static methods then there's not really any value in testing it anyway.

So you might end up with something like this, for example:

```
class UserPermissionWrapper {
    public function getUserPermission($user) {
        return UserPermission::scopeUser($user);
    }
}
```

Then you can inject that into your original class and get something like this:

```
public function userPermissionGranted(User $user, AbstractPermission $permission) : bool
{
    // Assume this is an instance of UserPermissionWrapper injected at construction
    $user_permission = $this->userPermissionWrapper
        ->getUserPermission($user)
        ->scopePermission($permission)
        ->first();

    return $user_permission ? $user_permission->isGranted() : $permission->isGrantedByDefault();
}
```

Now you have an object calling instance methods, so you can inject a mock version of that class and set up the method calls in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks! This is a useful answer. Only one thing I'm still wondering about. Technically my method is kind of testing if a database record exists, and if so it returns x, if not it returns y. In unit testing, should I simply not test all methods that do database related stuff and just assume that all that is working as it should? (I mean, that is what you do when mocking classes/methods anyway, right?)

Comment: (Maybe I mean methods that do exclusively database related stuff and return void)

Comment: I would say that testing the actual interaction with the database is more of an integration test.  Having an integration test suite that talks to a test database is a good thing, but it's more work to set up and maintain than a unit test suite.  That's why unit tests get so much emphasis - they provide a lot of value and are comparatively cheap to write.  For your case, since you're using a third-party ORM, I'd say that if your wrappers are thin enough then there's no need to test them.  The ORM should already be tested by its maintainers and there's no value in your duplicating that work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question - and I've only come to a reasonable answer after a while of writing some more unit tests - I guess what it comes down to is this:

When testing the `userPermissionGranted()` method, we're actually only validating that the method works as expected. We're fetching a model from the database, and we may assume that this model has been tested already in its own, separate test. Given that we may assume that this model works as intended, and that we cannot access the database here to fetch the actual model, we can use a mock of the model, which we customly build to work just the way it should work, without actually performing any database work. That's where Peter Geer's answer comes in. Our class should contain a method to fetch the model from the database, so that instead of fetching and returning the model from the database, we can set up a mock and return that instead. In this case that means that in the `return` line of the method we're testing, we're going to test a mocked `isGranted()` on `$user_permission` (which is the mock we created to return a value that we want it to return), **and** `isGrantedByDefault()` on the `$permission` mock that we passed to the method when we called it.